# Apply onclick event inside a span tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, clipboard.js

I am trying to apply an onclick event on a span tag but getting the following error. I guess I am doing it in the right way.

```
VM409 twitter-message-73266664:892 Uncaught ReferenceError: clip is not 
defined
at HTMLSpanElement.onclick
```

span tag

```
<td><span id="bootstrap_css_link" class="badge  btn btn-success bootstrap_css_link" onclick="clip(this.id)" data-clipboard-target="#clipboardExample1">copy</span></td>
```

clip method

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    function clip(clip_id){
        var clipboard = new ClipboardJS(clip_id);
        clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
          setTooltip(e.trigger, 'Copied!');
          hideTooltip(e.trigger);
          //alert("hello");
        });
     } 
});
```

Comment: Could you post how/where you load your JavaScript?

Comment: in document ready function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `clip` is inside a function, it's not accessible from outside it. Remove the `document.ready`:

```
function clip(clip_id) {
  var clipboard = new ClipboardJS(clip_id);
  clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
    setTooltip(e.trigger, 'Copied!');
    hideTooltip(e.trigger);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`clip` function is not available in global scope, since it's defined inside another function. You need to find the element and attach the event handler via JavaScript.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#bootstrap_css_link").on("click", clip);

  function clip(event) {
    console.log(event.target.id)

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td><span id="bootstrap_css_link" class="badge  btn btn-success bootstrap_css_link" data-clipboard-target="#clipboardExample1">copy</span></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('#bootstrap_css_link).click(function () {
var newArray
function clip(clip_id){
var clipboard = new ClipboardJS(clip_id);
clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
  setTooltip(e.trigger, 'Copied!');
hideTooltip(e.trigger);
//alert("hello");
});

 } 
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You must define the clip function outside of $( document ).ready so you just need to define the function like this

```
function clip(clip_id){
    var clipboard = new ClipboardJS(clip_id);
    clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
      setTooltip(e.trigger, 'Copied!');
      hideTooltip(e.trigger);
      //alert("hello");
    });
 }
```